# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

Tags: java, android, arrays

I get the following error in my android app:

The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = R.array.calc_categories[position]; //error on this line
    try {
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.calculator.commonCalculatios." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
```

Comment: Sounds like `calc_categories` is an `int` and not an array.

Comment: My father taught me, a long time ago, "don't argue with the compiler." The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. You think `calc_categories` is an array, but it's actually an `int`. If that doesn't make sense, time to investigate some code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
String openClass = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.calc_categories)[position]
```