# Expression must be an array, but ... to double

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to practice writing some code and  I can't solve my problem here. 
I keep getting for "double sideA,sideB,sideC" that the expression must be an array, but it resolved to double.

```
public static double Calculate (double array1, double array2, double array3) {

            double sideA = Math.sqrt(((array2[0]-array3[0])^2)+((array2[1]-array3[1])^2)+((array2[2]-array3[2])^2));
            double a= Math.abs(sideA);
            double sideB = Math.sqrt(((array1[0]-array3[0])^2)+((array1[1]-array3[1])^2)+((array1[2]-array3[2])^2));
            double b= Math.abs(sideB);
            double sideC = Math.sqrt(((array2[0]-array1[0])^2)+((array2[1]-array1[1])^2)+((array2[2]-array1[2])^2));
            double c= Math.abs(sideC);
            double s = ((0.5) * (a + b + c));
            return Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
    }
```

so can someone please help?

Comment: hey, i edited the post. the problem is that it keeps telling me that it should be an array (for double sideA,sideB,sideC) but it resolved to a double. I want to get a double, so how do i solve the problem ?

Comment: public static double Calculate (double[] array1, double[] array2, double[] array3) {

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155423/the-type-of-the-expression-must-be-an-array-type-but-it-resolved-to-int)

Comment: By the way, it seems like you are trying to raise to the power of 2 with `x^2` - this is incorrect, because `^` is a bitwise XOR operation. Do `Math.pow(x, 2)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array1`, despite the name, is *not actually an array* as you've written the code right now.  As you've written it, `array1` is just a single number.

Instead, it should be

```
public static double calculate(double[] array1, double[] array2, double[] array3) {
```

(Also, `^` does not do what you think it does; you would need `Math.pow`.  On the other hand, you can just write `Math.hypot(array2[0] - array1[0], array2[1] - array1[1])`.)